# Magento override customer address controller not working

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers

I am trying to override customer address controller but its't overrides

Config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <salesperson>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>VestricsB2B_Salesperson</module>
                <frontName>salesperson</frontName>
            </args>
            <!--<args>
                <modules>
                    <general before="Mage_Customer">VestricsB2B_Salesperson</general>
                </modules>
            </args>-->
        </salesperson>

        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <general before="Mage_Customer">VestricsB2B_Salesperson</general>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>

    <layout>
        <updates>
            <salesperson>
                <file>salesperson.xml</file>
            </salesperson>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

AccountController.php

```
 require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Customer').DS.'AddressController.php');
class VestricsB2B_Salesperson_AddressController extends Mage_Customer_AddressController {

    public function createPostAction(){
        echo "override"; exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to override **AddressController.php**? Well, there is no action in Magento core file **AddressController.php** with name `createPostAction`. You can try `formPostAction`

Comment: @JaiminSutariya , i changed to formPostAction but still not working. can you please confirm router configuration in my confi.xml script

Comment: Update `<general before="Mage_Customer">VestricsB2B_Salesperson</general>` to `<VestricsB2B_Salesperson before="Mage_Customer">VestricsB2B_Salesperson</VestricsB2B_Salesperson>`. Try updating your file name from **AccountController.php** to **AddressController.php**

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can try as:

```
...   
 <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <company_modulename before="Mage_Customer">Company_Modulename</company_modulename>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
...
```

And create a controller class: 
app/code/[codePool]/Company/Modulename/controllers/AccountController.php
with the following code:

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class Company_Modulename_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    public function createPostAction(){
        die('Overriden');
    } 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: i have another router in same config.xml can i add another router tag